# I can get IP address, but I cannot ping through that machine?

Tags: networking, ping

There's a machine in one of our domains that I want to ping. The machine's IP address is shown by the side of the machine's fully qualified domain name. So the DNS should be working. But there's no reply, it's always request time out. I tried to ping some other machines in the same domain, some can be pinged through, but some with the same problem.

What cause could it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the machine up with working networking?  Is it configured to allow you to connect?  All that being in DNS says is that DNS thinks it knows what machine the request should go to.  It says nothing about whether there is a machine that can respond at that IP address.

Comment: Just because a machine is on, connected to a network, and reachable from your machine, that doesn't automatically mean that it will respond to pings. Especially if there's say, a firewall in between filtering ICMP messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many machines are configured not to respond to ICMP Echo Requests (pings) and many firewalls will block them.  In this case, since other machines on the network are pingable, I'd say it's probably the individual target machine's configuration rather than a router that's ignoring you.